# Bind a checkbox to a detailsview

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to bind a checkbox to a details view as boolean 1,0. The database column is set to bit and not nulls. Below is my code,

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%#  Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("level"))%>' />
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox Enabled="false" ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  Checked='<%#  Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("level"))%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%#  Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("level"))%>' />
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'level'..." message when updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use edit or insert template you have to use `Bind`. `Eval` is only one way so your object is trying to insert a null value.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("level") %>' />
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox Enabled="false" ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%#  Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("level"))%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("level") %>' />
</InsertItemTemplate>
```